# The digits of a 3-digit integer are reversed to form a new integer of greater value. Find the new integer if their product is 91,567.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The digits of a 3-digit integer are reversed to form a new integer of greater value. The product of this new integer and the original integer is 91,567. What is the new integer?

Comment: [This](https://www.mathcounts.org/sites/default/files/u1706/2016%20State%20Sprint.pdf) is one of those state questions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability and there is nothing difficult in factoring $91567=7\cdot 103\cdot 127$.

Answer (score 2):

$127 * 721 = 91567$

The number ends in $7$ which means the 3 digit number must start with $1$ and end with $7$.

Comment: c.z.  Showed that the numbers must be $1x7$ and $7x1$, so we need merely solve $(1 \cdot 100 + x \cdot 10 + 7)(7 \cdot 100 + x \cdot 10 + 1) = 91567$ or $100 x^2+8080 x + 75007 - 91567 = 0$, which gives (for positive $x$), $x = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the original $3$ digit integer be $I$.

Let $I$ = $100a + 10b + c$, with $0 \leq a,b,c \leq 9$ and $c\geq a$

Then the new integer, $J = 100c + 10b + a$

We are given that $IJ = 91567 = (100a+10b+c)(100c+10b+a)$

So let's factorise $91567 = 7 \cdot 103 \cdot 127$

Then, since $I$ and $J$ are both integers, one of them is equal to $127$, and the other is equal to $7\cdot 103$. Since we are given that $J > I$, it follows that $J = 7 \cdot 103 = 721$ and $I = 127$

Now we must solve the following equations:

$721 = 100c + 10b + a$

$127 = 100a + 10b + c$

We can deduce that $a = 1$

Then we get $72 = 10c +b$

and $27 = 10b + c$

This implies:

$c = 27-10b, 72 = 270 -100b + b$

Then we get $b =2$ and $c = 7$

So the new integer is $721$